# How to get expert ranking on Chef Saltbaker in Cuphead?

Tags: cuphead

I've gotten past Chef Saltbaker one time by a miracle. But now, I'm trying to 300% Cuphead. Saltbaker is one of my last opponents to defeat on Expert mode, and I can't seem to find any strategy to get past his 2nd and last phase. Is there any strategy to get past him?